# Knitting R markdown (with plot() function) to PDF gives error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

While knitting an RMD to PDF, I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 47-76 (ABC.Rmd) 
Error in (function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf",  : 
  cannot open file '~/Read and visualize the "governorate" shapefile-1.pdf'
```

If I try to see it works for an HTML, then I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 47-76 (ABC.Rmd) 
Error in png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device
Calls: <Anonymous> ... in_dir -> plot2dev -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> png
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") :
  unable to open file '~/Read and visualize the "governorate" shapefile-1.png' for writing
2: In png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : opening device failed
```

Now I don't know if it has to do with the plot function, as I never get this error with "ggplot"

````
```{r Read and visualize the "governorate" shapefile, echo = FALSE}
# Import the Iraqi regions shapefile
Iraq_Regions =  readOGR(dsn = "~/governorates.shp")
# Import the Baghdad neighborhood shapefile 
Baghdad_Neigh = readOGR(dsn = "~/baghdad_neighborhoods.shp")
# Plot the Wiki Leaks data frame
plot(x=Wiki_Leaks$Longitude, y=Wiki_Leaks$Latitude, pch=20, col='red', cex=0.4)
plot(Iraq_Regions, border='blue', add=T)
plot(Baghdad_Neigh, border='yellow', add=T)

# Merge neighborhoods to make the Baghdad city outline
Greater_Baghdad <- gUnaryUnion(Baghdad_Neigh)

# Plot the shapefiles 
plot(x=Wiki_Leaks$Longitude, y=Wiki_Leaks$Latitude, pch=20, col='red', cex=0.4)
plot(Iraq_Regions, border='blue', add=T)
plot(Greater_Baghdad, border='yellow', add=T)

# view the names of different regions and the numbers of records in each region
#table(Wiki_Leaks$Region)

# Retrieve all events near Baghdad
Wiki_Leaks_MND_N_df = Wiki_Leaks[Wiki_Leaks$Region == "MND-N", ]

# Now make a basic plot
plot(x = Wiki_Leaks_MND_N_df$Long, y = Wiki_Leaks_MND_N_df$Lat,
     pch = 20, col = 'red', cex = 0.4,
     ylab = "Longitude", xlab = "Latitude", 
     main = "Death Events in Baghdad Neihborhood MND-N")

```
````

Comment: Does removing `"governorate"` change anything?

Comment: Yes, that worked, cheers. Can you explain why this was the cause of the error in an answer? and also now I am getting a Latex error: Error: LaTeX failed to compile ~.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Execution halted. Although, I do have "tinytex" and "MikTeK" installed.

Comment: I got it working after doing tinytex::install_tinytex(), so can you please explain the error being caused by "governorate" in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the punctuation marks while naming your code chunks, which will be used to name your files ([more information here, for example](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2013754/why-cant-i-use-punctuation-in-a-file-name.html)).

In your case, removing `"governorate"` would solve the problem.